# RSS feed XML & ATOM parse issue - GData - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, rss, xml-parsing, gdata

I have a question regarding the parsing of an XLM document more precisely the ATOM format data. (RSS feed).

Here is an sample of the xlm document:

```
<item>
            <title>Panty + Stocking Print Preview</title>
            <link>http://SonicRocksMySocks.deviantart.com/art/Panty-Stocking-Print-Preview-200615179</link>
            <guid isPermaLink="true">http://SonicRocksMySocks.deviantart.com/art/Panty-Stocking-Print-Preview-200615179</guid>
            <pubDate>Fri, 11 Mar 2011 21:43:34 PST</pubDate>
            <media:title type="plain">Panty + Stocking Print Preview</media:title>

            <media:keywords></media:keywords>
            <media:rating>nonadult</media:rating>
            <media:category label="Movies &amp; TV">fanart/digital/drawings/movies</media:category>
            <media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">SonicRocksMySocks</media:credit>
            <media:credit role="author" scheme="urn:ebu">http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/s/o/sonicrocksmysocks.png?15</media:credit> 
            <media:copyright url="http://sonicrocksmysocks.deviantart.com">Copyright 2011 *SonicRocksMySocks</media:copyright>
            <media:thumbnail url="http://th00.deviantart.net/fs71/300W/i/2011/070/d/c/panty___stocking_print_preview_by_sonicrocksmysocks-d3bfvnv.png" height="351" width="300"/>

            <media:thumbnail url="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs71/150/i/2011/070/d/c/panty___stocking_print_preview_by_sonicrocksmysocks-d3bfvnv.png" height="150" width="128"/>
            <media:content url="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/i/2011/070/d/c/panty___stocking_print_preview_by_sonicrocksmysocks-d3bfvnv.png" height="967" width="826" medium="image"/>
            <media:content url="http://www.deviantart.com/download/200615179/" medium="document"/>
            <description><![CDATA[ The final version of this print will be available for sale at Sakura Con 2011. :3<br /><div><img src="http://th00.deviantart.net/fs71/300W/i/2011/070/d/c/panty___stocking_print_preview_by_sonicrocksmysocks-d3bfvnv.png" alt="thumbnail" /></div> ]]></description>
            <media:description type="html"><![CDATA[ The final version of this print will be available for sale at Sakura Con 2011. :3 ]]></media:description>
        </item>
```

This is how I parse the title, pubDate and link values:

```
 NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) 
{            

    NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

    NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *item in items)
    {

        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
        NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];            
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];        
        NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];



        RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                                  articleTitle:articleTitle 
                                                    articleUrl:articleUrl 
                                                   articleDate:articleDate] autorelease];
        [entries addObject:entry];                        

    }      
}
```

I don't know how to retrieve the media:content line. How can I do it? 
Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you a lot,
Andrei

Comment: Well, I have no idea what library you're using, but you probably want to define the namespace for the `media` prefix to be whatever it is in your XML source (check your document's root element; it's probably set using an `xmlns` attribute there) somehow on your GDataXMLElement and then use that as part of your retrieval. Someone who knows more about GDataXMLelement, whatever library that's from, might be able to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried iterating through the children of `item` and examining them in the debugger or NSLog?

Comment: Thank you, but please explain what show I do? I am kind of a newbie

Comment: try adding NSLog(@"%@",item); near the start of your for loop. You may get some useful  output in the console.

Answer (score 0):

First u try using NSXMLParsing with this simple tutorial

```
http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/76999/parsing-xml-files/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know which code you're using. It's actually very simple.  You do it the same way you get the "title" and "link" and "pubDate".

```
 NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) 
{            

NSString *blogTitle = [channel valueForChild:@"title"];                    

NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
for (GDataXMLElement *item in items)
{

    NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
    NSString *articleUrl = [item valueForChild:@"link"];            
    NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];        
    NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];

    // Right here
    NSString *mediaCont = [item valueForChild:@"media:content"];



    RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:blogTitle 
                                              articleTitle:articleTitle 
                                                articleUrl:articleUrl 
                                               articleDate:articleDate] autorelease];
    [entries addObject:entry];                        

}      
}
```

After that you will need to alter your init method for RSSEntry to accept this new field. You should try to look at the code that defines valueForChild, and see how it's using the GDataXML parser. Or you could use NSXML as suggested.